# MYSQL Query with multiple WHEREs

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a very large DB.  I need to run a query to search by email and load_date (date/timestamped field).  I need to pull 3 email users from 3 different dates.

So I need a single table to display the emails (email field):

```
email1@host.com
nextemail@site.com
finalemail.yosite.com
```

for the dates (load_date field):

```
2014-08-01
2014-08-06
2014-08-09
```

If i run this:

```
SELECT email, load_date
  FROM table1
  WHERE email = 'email1@host.com' or email = 'nextemail@site.com' or email = 'finalemail.yosite.com
```

The results are correct.

If i run:

```
SELECT email, load_date
  FROM table1
  WHERE load_date LIKE "2014-08-01%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-06%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-09%"
```

The results are correct.

But if i combine them:

```
SELECT email, load_date
  FROM table1
  WHERE email = 'email1@host.com' or email = 'nextemail@site.com' or email = 'finalemail.yosite.com'
  and
   load_date LIKE "2014-08-01%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-6%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-09%"
```

I get everything!?

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: You need some parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

The AND function has a higher order of precedence than the OR function.  You need to encapsulate your ORs in parentheses.

```
SELECT email, load_date
FROM table1
WHERE (email = 'email1@host.com' or email = 'nextemail@site.com' or email = 'finalemail.yosite.com')
and (load_date LIKE "2014-08-01%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-6%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-09%")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parenthesis:

```
SELECT email, load_date
  FROM table1
  WHERE (email = 'email1@host.com' or email = 'nextemail@site.com' or email = 'finalemail.yosite.com'(
  and
   (load_date LIKE "2014-08-01%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-6%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-09%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary operators are evaluated from left to right, and `and` has precedence over `or`.

**Example:** If `condX` are boolean conditions, then `cond1 or cond2 and cond3 or cond4` is evaluated like this:

1. cond1 or cond2
2. [result of above] and cond3
3. [result of above] and cond4

If you want to "alter" the order of evaluation of your conditions, you must enclose them in parenthesis.

In your specific case, you must enclose in parenthesis the `email` comparissons  and the `load_date` comparissons:

```
WHERE 
    (email = 'email1@host.com' or email = 'nextemail@site.com' or email = 'finalemail.yosite.com')
  and (load_date LIKE "2014-08-01%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-6%" or load_date LIKE "2014-08-09%")
```

*The alternative:* Use `in`:

```
WHERE email in ('email1@host.com', 'nextemail@site.com', 'finalemail.yosite.com')
  AND date(load_date) in ("2014-08-01", "2014-08-6", "2014-08-09")
-- date(load_date) extracts the date part of the field
```